# Prepared statement in MySQL function

Tags: mysql

The below is working fine in MySQL statement but throws an error: "Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger" when creating a MySQL function.

```
SET @type='read';
SET @per_status=CONCAT('SELECT u.',@type,' INTO @res FROM user_permission u WHERE u.users_id = 2 AND u.web_pages_id=1');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @per_status;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
SELECT @res as 'Status';
```

This is what i have done so far but can't get rid of the error. your help will be appreciated.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`abi`@`localhost` FUNCTION `func_check_status`(`emp_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED, `type` VARCHAR(20), `page_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED) RETURNS varchar(20) CHARSET latin1
    NO SQL
BEGIN
DECLARE res_status varchar(20);

SET @per_status=CONCAT('SELECT u.',type,' INTO @res FROM user_permission u WHERE u.users_id = 2 AND u.web_pages_id=1');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @per_status;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
SET res_status = (SELECT @res);
RETURN res_status;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

---

### EDIT

According to [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html) I understand prepared statements can only be used in procedures and not in functions or triggers. With the help of @wchiquito's [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fozuwsHqZYPPBSiFvEAmF9/0) I tried to use the procedure containing the prepared statement inside another procedure which I needed to. But I am still getting syntax error.

Is it possible to use the procedure inside the select query and if yes then how? Please can anyone help?

Below is the demo I have tried:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`abi`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes`(IN `emp_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED, IN `type` VARCHAR(20), IN `page_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED, OUT `res_status` VARCHAR(3))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
  SET @`emp_id` := `emp_id`,
      @`page_id` := `page_id`,
      @`per_status` := CONCAT('
        SELECT `u`.`', `type`, '` INTO @`res_status`
        FROM `user_permission` `u`
        WHERE `u`.`users_id` = ? AND `u`.`web_pages_id` = ?
      ');
  PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`per_status`;
  EXECUTE `stmt` USING @`emp_id`, @`page_id`;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
  SET `res_status` := @`res_status`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`abi`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_select_pages_list`(IN `emp_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED)
    NO SQL
select 
`web_pages`.`web_pages_id` as 'ID',
`web_pages`.`name` 'Name',
`web_pages`.`page_name` as 'Page Name',
concat('<input type="checkbox" value="',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'read',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'" id="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[read]"  name="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[read]" onclick="change_permission(''',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[read]'');" ',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'read',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'>') as 'Read',
concat('<input type="checkbox" value="',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'insert',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'" id="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[insert]"   name="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[insert]" onclick="change_permission(''',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[insert]'');" ',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'insert',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'>') as 'Insert',
concat('<input type="checkbox" value="',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'edit',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'" id="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[edit]"  name="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[edit]" onclick="change_permission(''',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[edit]'');" ',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'edit',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'>') as 'Edit',
concat('<input type="checkbox" value="',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'delete',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'" id="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[delete]" name="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[delete]" onclick="change_permission(''',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[delete]'');" ',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'delete',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'>') as 'Delete',
concat('<input type="checkbox" value="',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'update',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'" id="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[update]" name="',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[update]" onclick="change_permission(''',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,'[update]'');" ',(call sp_checked_attr_for_permission_checkboxes(emp_id,'update',`web_pages`.`web_pages_id`,@res_status); SELECT @res_status;),'>') as 'Update'
FROM
`web_pages`
WHERE
`web_pages`.`status` = 'active'

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).`, see [Chapter 2 Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html). Can you use a stored procedure?.

Comment: @wchiquito i need to get it from a function as i will use this function in a store procedure

Comment: @AbdalAsif you cannot use `PREPARE` inside a stored function under any circumstances.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot any other way beside prepare statement? I want to use the parameter as a column name in the query

Comment: also i need a function so i can call it in my procedure.

Comment: Any time you find yourself needing to use a *value* as an *identifier*, that is a sign that you may have departed from solid database design principles. In this case, you should probably have something like a `user_has_permission_type` table with `(user_id, permission_type_id)` as its primary key. However... there is a workaround that might be potentially useful, depending on how many different column names are involved.  How many are there?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot please chech the fiddle: [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ddvS5hjPsd96TdurxLJm9j/0)

Comment: Have you considered using an output parameter in a stored procedure?, an option can be [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fozuwsHqZYPPBSiFvEAmF9/0).

Comment: @wchiquito i did think of that but thought procedure in procedure won't work, only function will. let me check this but as far as i think this is the solution.

Comment: @wchiquito i executed your example individually it works fine, I wonder where am i making mistake while putting it in a select query. For e.g:  `select users_id as 'ID', CALL sp_test2('emp_id', 'update', 'page_id', @`status`); @status as 'status' from user_permission`. not sure if its a correct syntax to call a procedure with output variable in a select query